# Inconsistent behavior of Elasticsearch with multiple must_not condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on NodeJs based API and it is build with Elasticsearch and NodeJs.
I have to provide a functionality where API users can exclude some content based on the taxonomy terms.

**freeform:** Multi-value field - type : string

**games:** Multi-value field - type : string

**players:** Multi-value field - type : string

**teams:** Multi-value field - type : string

**writer:** Multi-value field - type : string

**channels:** Multi-value field - type : string

Format of API url will be something similar to below.
https://api.test.net/2/xxxxx/article/?exclude=term1+term2

Above should return the content which is not tagged to term1 and term2.

Suppose we have 3 articles, first article is tagged to term1, second article is tagged to term2 and third article is tagged to term1 and term2.

**Expected Result:**
https://api.test.net/2/xxxxx/article/?exclude=term1+term2 should return article first(tagged to term1), second article(tagged to term2) and not the third(Tagged to term1 and term2)

**Actual Result:**
Sometimes https://api.test.net/2/xxxxx/article/?exclude=term1+term2 returns all three articles and sometime first(tagged to term1) and second article(tagged to term2).

**Update:**
Below is the correct doc and I have added the query also but still I am seeing the inconsistency.

**Doc:**

```
{
   "team":{
      "mappings":{
         "article":{
            "properties":{
               "body":{
                  "properties":{
                     "content":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "html":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "type":{
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "brand":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "changed":{
                  "type":"date",
                  "format":"dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "changedUtc":{
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "content":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "created":{
                  "type":"date",
                  "format":"dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "createdUtc":{
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "domain":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "headline":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "langcode":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "nid":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "published":{
                  "type":"date",
                  "format":"dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "publishedUtc":{
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "raw":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"no"
               },
               "revisionTimestamp":{
                  "type":"date",
                  "format":"dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "revisionTimestampUtc":{
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "status":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "subheadline":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "syndication":{
                  "properties":{
                     "brand":{
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "options":{
                        "properties":{
                           "actionFrom":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "publish":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "status":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "type":{
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "taxonomy":{
                  "properties":{
                     "coaches":{
                        "properties":{
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "freeform":{
                        "properties":{
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "games":{
                        "properties":{
                           "id":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "players":{
                        "properties":{
                           "id":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "section":{
                        "properties":{
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "teams":{
                        "properties":{
                           "city":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "id":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "nickname":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "tricode":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "urlName":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "writer":{
                        "properties":{
                           "emailAddress":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "id":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "responsive_web":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "title":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "value":{
                              "type":"string"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "teaser":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "title":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "type":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "url":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "uuid":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               },
               "vid":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
   "filter":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            [
               {
                  "term":{
                     "status":1
                  }
               }
            ]
         ],
         "must":[

         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "_source":{
      "include":[
         "uuid",
         "nid",
         "type",
         "title",
         "headline",
         "shortHeadline",
         "teaser",
         "url",
         "published",
         "changed",
         "subheadline",
         "listImage",
         "brand",
         "videoId",
         "videoSource",
         "duration",
         "taxonomy",
         "includeTerms",
         "excludeTerms",
         "media",
         "credit",
         "caption",
         "description",
         "videoCaptions",
         "franchiseId",
         "showAirTime",
         "slateImage",
         "mainImage",
         "thumbnailImage",
         "showTitle",
         "status",
         "pubstatus"
      ]
   },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "query":"langcode:\"en\""
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":{
                     "query_string":{
                        "query":"(taxonomy.freeform.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.freeform.value:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.games.id:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.games.id:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.players.id:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.players.id:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.teams.id:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.teams.id:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.writer.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.writer.value:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.channels.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.channels.value:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.section.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.section.value:\"nullam\") "
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "publishedUtc":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      },
      {
         "_score":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the multivalued fields?

Comment: @NishantSaini I have added type in the description and it is string for all the fields.

Comment: What do you mean by tagged? If term1 appears in any one of the 7 fields you mentiones, will that doc be considered as tagged as term1?

Comment: Also can you share a sample doc?

Comment: @NishantSaini I have added the doc to the question as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have mapping something similar to this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "taxonomy": {
          "properties": {
            "game": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "team": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The required query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(t1 OR t2) NOT (t1 AND t2)",
            "fields": [
              "taxonomy.game.keyword",
              "taxonomy.team.keyword"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the document you provided your field list will be:

```
"fields":[
    "taxonomy.teams.id",
    "taxonomy.freeform.value",
    "taxonomy.games.id",
    "taxonomy.players.id",
    "taxonomy.writer.value",
    "taxonomy.coaches.value"
    ]
```

Please note that I assumed `id`, `value` are `keyword` type. In case they are not then please change the mapping. Also if the mapping is dynamically created then there will be a sub-field name `keyword` under `id`, `value`, in a way similar to the example mapping I have used which has `keyword` field under `game` and `team`.

The above works for elasticsearch 6.x

**Update based on query added to question:**

The `must_not` part in your query should be logically:

```
(f1=t1 AND f1=t2) OR (f2=t1 AND f2=t2) OR (f3=t1 AND f3=t2) ....
```

where **f** *i* represents field and **t** *i* represents term.

So the `must_not` part should be:

```
{
  "must_not": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(taxonomy.freeform.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.freeform.value:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.games.id:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.games.id:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.players.id:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.players.id:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.teams.id:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.teams.id:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.writer.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.writer.value:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.channels.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.channels.value:\"nullam\") OR (taxonomy.section.value:\"sociosqu\" AND taxonomy.section.value:\"nullam\") "
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the correct doc and have added the query as per your suggestion but still I am seeing the inconsistency in the results.

Comment: @MohammadAnwar What version of elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: I have updated answer based on your query, though its still not clear when a document is considered to be tagged? You haven't shared a sample doc yet for the same.

Comment: I am using below version.
"version": {
"number": "1.5.0",
"build_hash": "544816042d40151d3ce4ba4f95399d7860dc2e92",
"build_timestamp": "2015-03-23T14:30:58Z",
"build_snapshot": false,
"lucene_version": "4.10.4"
}

Comment: I am new to Elastic Search so don't know what is sample doc. If possible please let me know how to get the sample doc and I will share it with you.

Comment: I have corrected my query but still I am getting the inconsistent results

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nishant Saini... It was not a code issue but the build issue... we have 2 origin servers... For first origin server deployment was successful and for second server build was failing... That's why I was getting inconsistent results.